Ngrok Executable Flagged as Potentially Unwanted Software by Microsoft Defender
We encountered an issue where the Ngrok executable, which is used for connecting the parent bot to the child bot, was flagged and quarantined as potentially unwanted software by Microsoft Defender. This software is mentioned as tunneling software to connect the bot locally in the Microsoft Bot Framework documentation.
Ngrok was used by us for a very long time and was working fine. And it suddenly started getting blocked by Windows Defender.
The error message in Windows Defender is "Defender detected and quarantined active 'PUA
/Ngrok!MTB' in file 'ngrok.exe' during a scheduled scan."
What could the possible solution or is there any other alternative software for Ngrok that I can use for tunneling the bot endpoint?
Any additional steps to whitelist or properly configure the use of Ngrok in the development environment would be highly appreciated.
We executed the Ngrok executable to establish a connection between the parent bot and the child bot, as per the Microsoft Bot Framework documentation.
It usually connects the parent bot to the child bot.

If you open Windows Defender (Windows Security), you should see where it has blocked ngrok previously.  At that point, you can choose to "Allow" in the bottom right button of the information section.  Once you do that, ngrok should no longer be blocked and will execute successfully.
